# Laplace transform of rapidly increasing function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the following 3 `LaplaceTransform` expressions.  I believe that the first two are valid (at least for `k>0`).  The third puzzles me, as I am not aware that the transform is defined for such rapidly increasing functions.

```
lp1 = LaplaceTransform[Exp[-t^2], t, s]
(* 1/2 E^(s^2/4) Sqrt[π] Erfc[s/2] *)

lp2 = LaplaceTransform[Exp[-k t^2], t, s]
(* (E^(s^2/(4 k)) Sqrt[π] Erfc[s/(2 Sqrt[k])])/(2 Sqrt[k]) *)

lp3 = LaplaceTransform[Exp[t^2], t, s]
(* -(1/2) I E^(-(s^2/4)) Sqrt[π] + DawsonF[s/2] *)
```

I note that the behaviour is consistent with what is given by substitution.

```
lp3 == lp2 /. k -> -1 // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

However, Mathematica cannot compute an inverse transform for `lp3`

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[{lp1, lp2, lp3}, s, t]
(* {E^-t^2, E^(-k t^2), 
 InverseLaplaceTransform[-(1/2) I E^(-(s^2/4)) Sqrt[π] + 
   DawsonF[s/2], s, t]} *)
```

Question: is the Laplace transform defined for such rapidly increasing functions (I would appreciate a reference)?

Comment: The question of the existence of a Laplace Transform for Exp[t^2] is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1288090) , but there's no definitive conclusion. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545257) is related too, but not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any evidence that a valid meaning can be given to this Laplace transform.  In Mathematica 13.0.1, it is returned unevaluated, suggesting that the previous behaviour was not intended.

```
lp3 = LaplaceTransform[Exp[t^2], t, s]
(* LaplaceTransform[E^t^2, t, s] *)
```